# How do I generate a Loader_Generate_Script for all states and regions?

Tags: postgis, geocoding

I'm using PostGIS and I'm wondering how do I generate a loader script for all states that will load all of the census dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this is stored in `tiger.state`

```
SELECT stusps,name,division,statefp
FROM tiger.state
ORDER BY name;
```

The script expects it's arguments in the form of the two character `stusps` code,

```
\t
\a
\o /gisdata/statescript.sh
SELECT Loader_Generate_Script(ARRAY['AL' , 'AK' , 'AS' , 'AZ' , 'AR' , 'CA' , 'CO' , 'MP' , 'CT' , 'DE' , 'DC' , 'FL' , 'GA' , 'GU' , 'HI' , 'ID' , 'IL' , 'IN' , 'IA' , 'KS' , 'KY' , 'LA' , 'ME' , 'MD' , 'MA' , 'MI' , 'MN' , 'MS' , 'MO' , 'MT' , 'NE' , 'NV' , 'NH' , 'NJ' , 'NM' , 'NY' , 'NC' , 'ND' , 'OH' , 'OK' , 'OR' , 'PA' , 'PR' , 'RI' , 'SC' , 'SD' , 'TN' , 'TX' , 'VI' , 'UT' , 'VT' , 'VA' , 'WA' , 'WV' , 'WI' , 'WY'], 'sh');
```

*(the method of `\t \a \o` was borrowed from [PostGIS in Action Second Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1617291390))*

Answer (score 0):

You can also dynamically create the array.

**Bash**

```
psql -c "select loader_generate_script(array(select stusps from tiger.state), 'sh')" -tA > /gisdata/all_load.sh
```

**Postgres**

```
\t
\a
\o /gisdata/all_load.sh
select loader_generate_script(array(select stusps from tiger.state), 'sh');
```